# Recursive Reverse Function

Tags: c++, function, pointers, recursion, reverse

I was wondering whether someone could explain how this small code snippet works.

```
void reverse(char *s)
{
   if(*s)
       reverse(s+1);
   else
       return;

   cout << *s;
}
```

When you call this function in main, it supposedly prints out the reverse of any string put in (ie. hello would cout as olleh) but I don't understand how. As I understand it, the if statement increases the value of s until it reaches the end of the string, printing out each value in the string as it goes. Why doesn't that just re-print the string. Clearly I am missing something. (Sorry btw, I am new to C++ and recursive functions)

Comment: Try hand-rolling a SHORT string ("cat" or "dog" springs to mind) through this function and record on paper, one step at a time, what happens. You may want to study up on pointer arithmetic first.

Comment: The thing you might be tripping up on is that the string has a \0 at the end, so there's an exit condition for the `if` statement.

Comment: FYI you can also use std::reverse

Comment: @RobertHarvey I understand that there is an exit condition. However, doesn't that just mean *s is pointing to the last value in the string? How are the rest of the values printed out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how the `"hello"` string is stored in memory: let's say the address of its `'h'` character happens to be `0xC000`. Then the rest of the string would be stored as follows:

```
0xC000 'h'
0xC001 'e'
0xC002 'l'
0xC003 'l'
0xC004 'o'
0xC005 '\0'
```

Now consider a series of invocations of `reverse`: the initial invocation passes `0xC000`; the call of `reverse` from inside the reverse passes `s+1`, so the next level gets `0xC001`; the next one gets `0xC002`, and so on.

Note that each level calls the next level, until the level that sees `'\0'`. Before we get to zero, the stack is "loaded" like this:

```
reverse(0xC004) // the last invocation before we hit '\0'
reverse(0xC003)
reverse(0xC002)
reverse(0xC001)
reverse(0xC000) // the earliest invocation
```

Now when the top invocation calls `reverse(0xC005)`, the check for `*s` fails, and the function returns right away without printing anything. At this point the stack starts "unwinding", printing whatever is pointed to by its `s` argument:

```
0xC004 -> prints 'o', then returns to the previous level
0xC003 -> prints 'l', then returns to the previous level
0xC002 -> prints 'l', then returns to the previous level
0xC001 -> prints 'e', then returns to the previous level
0xC000 -> prints 'h', then returns for good.
```

That's how the reverse of the original `"hello"` string gets printed.

Answer (score 3):

Try visualizing how the call stack builds up. Each recursive call creates another stack frame with a copy of `s` incremented by one. When the exit condition occurs, the stack starts unwinding and `cout` statement gets called for each frame. Because of LIFO principle, the string is printed in reverse.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's consider a string of length 3. `reverse(i)` is short for the function called on the i-th index of the string (well technically it's the char pointer + i, but that explanation requires a little more advanced understanding).

It's also useful to note (as Robert pointed out) that `*s` returns false if `s` points to `\0`, which indicates the end of the string, so, in this case, it will simply return.

Here's what happens:

```
reverse(0)
  calls reverse(1)
    calls reverse(2)
      calls reverse(3)
        end of string - return
      prints 2
    prints 1
  prints 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at a simple example, assume s = "the"

We would have:

rev(t) ->increment pointer

rev(h)->increment pointer

rev(e) ->increment pointer

rev('\0')  (this would just return)

Then we would be back in the body of rev(e) which would print e

Then back to rev(h) which would print h

Then finally back to rev(t) which would print t

In that order then we would have: eht ("the" in reverse)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it would be clearer to write the function as:

```
void reverse(const char *s)
{
   if(*s)
   {
     reverse(s+1);
     std::cout << *s;
   }
}
```

i.e each not null characther will be printed after calling the next one (by the calling to reverse)

PD: Use "const char*" instead of "char*" if you will not modify the given string.